# Fingerprint Reader For Android App

Tags: android, fingerprint

I want to build an android app in which the attendance of the person can be viewed when the person touches the fingerprint reader. The fingerprint reader would be placed outside every classroom in the college. Is this possible through android app? If not possible through fingerprint, then kindly suggest any other alternative through android app.

Comment: I think that this is not the right site to ask it.
http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would not be possible directly using the fingerprint scanner on an Android device, as the fingerprint data is stored securely on the device, and not available to any applications. The [Fingerprint Authentication API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#fingerprint-authentication) only provides whether or not a fingerprint registered on the device was touched to the scanner, it does not differentiate between individual fingerprints.

You should be able to use a third-party fingerprint scanner that connects to an Android device and *does* differentiate between individual fingerprints. A quick search lead me to the [U.are.U SDK for Android](http://www.crossmatch.com/uareu-sdk-for-android/), which seems to provide this functionality for their products.

Another option is to use a third-party mag-stripe card reader (provided the students have an ID card with a mag-stripe) that connects to an Android device, of which a variety of options are available.